# Centering logo with header on low resolutions

Tags: html, css

This is my code I've added this outer div and tried out different methods as you can see in style trying to center logo with Patch header

```
 echo '<div style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"><a       
 href="index.php"><div id="logo"></div></a>';
                echo '<h1 class="patch">PATCH ';
                    echo $patch.'</h1></div>
```

Here is also css  I have the problem with max-width 639 px and smaller that is how it looks https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZWxf.png

```
#logo {
            float: left;
            width: 37px;
            height: 37px;

            background-image: url("../assets/logo/logo.png");
            background-size: contain;
        }
        #logo:hover{
            background-image: url("../assets/logo/logo_inverted.png");
            background-size: contain;
            transition: all 500ms ease; 
        }

@media only screen
        and (min-width: 640px)
        {
        .patch{
            float: left;
        }
        #logo{
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
}
@media(max-width: 639px){
        #logo{
            float: none;
            }
        .patch{
            float: none;
        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
```

to .patch and you are all set. Why use margin auto on a text if you don't need to?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/p0ZQk1I.png with width 100% added to and text-align. I used margins to play around and try to move it somehow

Comment: still doesn't I sent you the link with the picture of how it looks currently